# KLEE does not find uninitialized variable error

Tags: klee

I am learning KLEE now and I wrote a simple code:

```
#include "klee/klee.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(int *p)
{
    int *q = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    if ((*p) == (*q)) {
       printf("reading uninitialized heap memory");
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    test(p);
    return 0;
}
```

First, I generate LLVM bitcode, and then I execute KLEE to the bitcode.
Following is all output:

```
KLEE: output directory is "/Users/yjy/WorkSpace/Test/klee-out-13"
Using STP solver backend
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: printf
KLEE: WARNING ONCE: calling external: printf(140351601907424)
reading uninitialized heap memory
KLEE: done: total instructions = 61
KLEE: done: completed paths = 4
KLEE: done: generated tests = 4
```

I suppose that KLEE should give me an error that the q pointer is not initialized, but it doesn't. Why KLEE does not give me an error or warning about this? KLEE can not detect this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**TLTR**: KLEE has not implemented this feature. Clang can check this directly.

KLEE currently support add/sub/mul/div overflow checking. To use this feature, you have to compile the source code with clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow or clang -fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow .

The idea is that a function call is inserted into the bytecode (e.g. __ubsan_handle_add_overflow) when you use the clang sanitizer. Then KLEE will handle the overflow checking once it meets the function call.

Clang support 
 [MemorySanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html), [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html). They are defined in projects/compiler-rt/lib directory. MemorySanitizer is the one you are looking for, which is a detector of uninitialized reads.

You can remove the KLEE function call and check with clang directly.

```
➜  ~ clang -g -fsanitize=memory st.cpp
➜  ~ ./a.out
==16031==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x490954  (/home/hailin/a.out+0x490954)
    #1 0x7f21b72f382f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #2 0x41a1d8  (/home/hailin/a.out+0x41a1d8)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value (/home/hailin/a.out+0x490954)
Exiting
```